# ¿Cómo puedo recorrer todas las filas de un GridView, después de haberle agregado paginado con la librería DataTable?

Tags: asp.net, .net, datatables, asp, gridview

**Estimados un cordial saludo,**

alguien conoce cómo puedo recorrer todas las filas de un gridview (toda la tabla), la cual le he agregado paginado con la libreria DataTable. Actualmente sólo me permite recorrer la página actual (visible), desde el evento: rowcommand.

**Les agradezco sus comentarios.**

Answer (score 0):

Compañeros, encontré una solución bastante simple pero efectiva y es realizar un "destroy()" del DataTable, antes de recorrer el gridview y Listo¡¡¡. De esta forma, puedo obtener toda la data que DataTable tenía almacenada en caché y la que yo iba ingresando en los input="text" de la tabla; finalmente reasigno nuevamente el datatable a la tabla y asunto solucionado.

**Espero a alguien más, le sea de utilidad. Gracias.**